Define DLT pipeline that depends on event log
I want to define a table "DEMO" using DLT pipeline. This table includes data from the event log. Here is a simplified and anonymized example of what I want to do. I really need this information, to track my pipelines.
def event_log_update_id():
    return spark.sql("select origin.update_id from event_log(table(catalog.default.DEMO)) order by timestamp desc limit 1;").first().update_id

@dlt.table(name="DEMO")
def table():
    return (
        spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
              .option("cloudFiles.Format", "csv")
              .load("abfss://...")
              .withColumn("update_id", lit(event_log_update_id()))
    )

Sometimes it is getting an empty result when creating a table from scratch, doing a full load. I am thinking that since the table does not yet exist, I cannot access the event log by specifying the table name.
How can I achieve my goal? I cannot help but think that I am doing something wrong.

You table is created only when you execute you dlt pipeline but when you are running it for the first time the table will be not created and raises an error table not found.
So, you handle this case by using pipeline id to get latest update id instead of table name. Also, you need to check for table existence for the initial load, if table doesn't exists get update id using pipeline id like below.
result = spark.sql("SELECT origin.update_id FROM event_log('<yourPipelineID>') WHERE event_type = 'create_update' ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1;").first().update_id

If table exists then you query using  table name.
Below is the sample code.
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,col
from delta import DeltaTable

def event_log_update_id():
    table_exists = DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark,"jgsbricks.default.DEMO")
    
    if table_exists:
        result = spark.sql("select origin.update_id from event_log(table(jgsbricks.default.DEMO)) order by timestamp desc limit 1;").first().update_id
    else:
        #Give the pipeline id
        result = spark.sql('SELECT origin.update_id FROM event_log("99104xxxxxx5") order by timestamp desc limit 1;').first().update_id 

    return result


data = [
    (1, "Alice", "2024-08-01", 1000000),
    (2, "Bob", "2024-08-02", 1500000),
    (3, "Charlie", "2024-08-03", 2000000)
]


columns = ["id", "name", "date", "amount"]

@dlt.table(name="DEMO")
def table():
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns).withColumn("update_id", lit(event_log_update_id()))
    return df

Here, if the table is not created then using pipeline id i am getting the event logs and returning update id.
Refer this documentation for more ways to create event log table.
Output:

And the same id is created in table.

UPDATE
You configure the dlt pipeline settings with pipeline id like below and save it.

Make sure you give the value in quotes.
Next, use below code for your function.
def event_log_update_id():
    pipelineId = spark.conf.get("pipeid")
    result = spark.sql(f"""
        SELECT origin.update_id,timestamp FROM event_log({pipelineId}) ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1;
        """).first()
    return result.update_id


Thanks. Your answer assumes you know the pipeline id, but I do not know it. How would I also get the pipeline id from dlt itself?

Also your answer assumes you know the catalog and schema name. Is it possible to get them from the code itself? When creating a dlt compute resource, you can set these values there. How would one obtain that information?

You will get the pipeline id in ui when you create it. it is constant and doesn't change. You should be knowing the pipeline id without it you can't query event logs table. because for the first run you table will be not created so at least for the initial load you should be knowing.

Also you can get the pipeline id just by querying event logs through table name like this select origin.pipeline_id from event_log(table(jgsbricks.default.DEMO)) limit 1; but for initial load gives you the error. Please refer the provided doc on how to get event log based on the storage option used.

I have updated solution for dynamic access the pipeline id which is still you need to configure it in dlt settings.
